# Can I replace Slater boxless receptacles with conventional ones?

Tags: electrical

Most of my receptacles have stopped working on one side.  When I went to replace them, I found out that they are Slater Boxless Receptacles.  Can I replace the Slater ones with
conventional outlets?

Comment: On one side of what?

Comment: Those are RV outlets. See http://www.google.com/patents/US3860319 http://www.google.com/patents/US4500746

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you MUST cut in old work device boxes first. You CANNOT simply install standard receptacles in the holes in the walls.

Here is an example:

[image]